# How do I reduce spaces between checkboxListTile

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, android-layout

I have an array of strings i map through to use as the labels different Checkbox using a CheckboxListTile Widget but i need to reduce the space inbetween these checkboxs.

```
  @override
  _CheckBoxInListviewState createState() => _CheckBoxInListviewState();
}

class _CheckBoxInListviewState extends State<CheckBoxInListview> {
  // bool _isChecked = false;

 Map<String,bool> _texts = {
    "InduceSmile.com": false,
    "google.com": false,
    "youtube.com": false,
    "yahoo.com": false,
 };
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return  Column(
          
          children: _texts.keys.map((text) => Theme(
            data: ThemeData(

                    checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
                      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(4),topRight: Radius.circular(4),bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),bottomRight: Radius.circular(4))))),
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              title: Transform.translate(offset: Offset(-15,0),
              child: Text(text,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),),
              ),
               value: _texts[text],
                  onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                   _texts[text] = val;
            
                });
              },
            ),
          )).toList(),
  );
  }
}
```

this is the result of my code
[here is the picture(result of the code above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtcvy.png)

Comment: `ListTile`s have fixed height so that hitting them is easy - you cannot reduce that height, the docs for `ListTile` says: *"A single fixed-height row that typically contains some text as well as a leading or trailing icon."*

Comment: so whats a better way of soving this then?

Comment: go to [CheckboxListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html) documentation and find `CheckboxListTile isn't exactly what I want` section

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @pskink the `CheckboxListTile` is like fixed height component with only `contentPadding` to adjust the space around the content and not else can be controlled.

However, You can increase the size of the font of  your Text widget to provide a better UI - Below is the screen shot of how it would look with font size of 28.

[image]